# The method used in mapstruct with qualified by name isn't used in autogenerated implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

I have the following DTO and Entity classes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CType {

    private Integer id;
    // ......
    private VType vType;
}
```

---

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "c_types")
public class CTypeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    // ......

    @Column(name = "v_type_id")
    private Integer vTypeId;
}
```

I need to map the objects of these classes with *mapstruct* and this is my *mapstruct*:

```
@Mapper
public interface VCMapper {

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "cType", qualifiedByName = "formVType")
    })
    CType toCType(CTypeEntity cTypeEntity);

    List<CType> toCTypes(List<CTypeEntity> cTypeEntities);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "vTypeId", source = "vType.id")
    })
    CTypeEntity fromCType(CType cType);

    List<CTypeEntity> fromCTypeList(List<CType> cTypes);

    @Named("formVType")
    default VType formVType(CTypeEntity entity, @Context VTypeDao vTypeDao) {
        return vTypeDao.findById(entity.getVId()); 
    }
}
```

**Problem:** When I build my application with maven (`mvn clean package`), the implementation of the method `toCType()` in auto-generated `VCMapperImpl` class doesn't use the qualified `formVType()` default method.

**Questions:**

- Why the qualified default method isn't used in impl class?
- What is wrong with the default method and it's usage in Mapper interface and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi Armine, did you find any solution for this problem. Having the same issue.

Comment: No, I didn't find a good solution, I just overcame it: I removed @Context from the formVType() second argument, and after each time when I call toCType() in my dao or wherever, I manually call formVType() by passing appropriate dao object. Not good, but at that time that was the fastest way.

Comment: kind a expected this kind of answer, will do the same to get a fast result ;)

Thx for the reply

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the qualified `formVType` method is not used is because of the `@Context` attribute. There is no such attribbtute in the originating method so MapStruct will nnot match the method. If you add that to `toCType` then it would be used.

In order not to drag the `VTypeDao` I would suggest that you use an `abstract` class and inject it into it.

E.g.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class VCMapper {

    protected VTypeDao vTypeDao;

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "cType", qualifiedByName = "formVType")
    })
    public abstract CType toCType(CTypeEntity cTypeEntity);

    public abstract List<CType> toCTypes(List<CTypeEntity> cTypeEntities);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "vTypeId", source = "vType.id")
    })
    public abstract CTypeEntity fromCType(CType cType);

    public abstract List<CTypeEntity> fromCTypeList(List<CType> cTypes);

    @Named("formVType")
    protected VType formVType(CTypeEntity entity) {
        return vTypeDao.findById(entity.getVId()); 
    }

    public void setVTypeDao(VTypeDao vTypeDao) {
        this.vTypeDao = vTypeDao
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the suggested options worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a new class where you can define two methods that:

1. convert a Integer vTypeId into a VType
2. convert a VType vType into an Integer

Than you can use this class into your mapstruct class by providing that in "uses=" property on the @Mapper annotation.
Than what you need to do is to simply specify in the Object method the @Mapping specification, in your case it would be:

```
@Mapping(target="vType",source="vTypeId")
CType toCType(CTypeEntity cTypeEntity);

@Mapping(target="vTypeId",source="vType")
CTypeEntity toCTypeEntity(CType cTypeEntity);
```

The custom class to use separately:

```
@Component
public class VtypeResolver{
  @Autowired
  private VTypeDao dao;


  public VType toVType(Integer id) {
    if (id != null) {
        return dao.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
    return null;
  }


  public Integer toVtypeId(VType input) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(input)
            .map(VType::getId)
            .orElse(null);
  }


 }
```

then use in @Mapper context

```
@Mapper(uses=VTypeResolver.class){
....
}
```